# CSS - animations for a carousel of multiple items

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, carousel

I created a multiple items carousel, and I want to add sliding animations to it.

For example, on click right, I want that the displayed items will fade out from right to left, and the new items will replace them from right to left as well (but the new ones will come from out of the screen)

I'm using CSS grid for the layout of the items:

`display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2.5rem); gap: 1rem;`

and I'm hiding the items that are not relevant to the displayed slide using `visibility: hidden`.

Here is an abstract example of the carousel - https://jsfiddle.net/dehxzLn6/48/

As you can see, the `visibility: hidden` property is hiding the elements, but they still taking space, so it's another issue that I need to solve.

I would be very happy if you could help me figure out how to add animations to a carousel like this.

thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: `display: none;`  instead of `visibility: hidden` might be the solution to the spacing issue. as for the animation i suggest you make a parent div of fixed width and let the elements not displayed overflow in the bg, then on click scroll it by the same amount as the width of the parent to give it a sliding animation

Comment: I know that `display: none` does not work with animations

Answer (score 1):

As answered before me, "visibility: hidden" elements take up space on the page, so you can use the display property instead.

Other option is to 'stack' the items in position. There's a few ways to it, like the position property, but you're using grid, so you can use grid-areas.

As for the animation, you can use the opacity property and transition it. And to get the effect you want, you can add a delay according to the position...

```
.items-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c d"
    "e f g h";
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: auto 0;

  .item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(46, 37, 37, 0.15), 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(203, 205, 208, 0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    transition: opacity 0.8s calc(var(--delay) + var(--delayOffset, 0s));

    &.is-hidden {
      opacity: 0;
      --delayOffset: -0.8s;
    }

    &.pos0 { grid-area: a; --delay: 0.8s; }
    &.pos1 { grid-area: b; --delay: 0.9s; }
    &.pos2 { grid-area: c; --delay: 1.0s; }
    &.pos3 { grid-area: d; --delay: 1.1s; }
    &.pos4 { grid-area: e; --delay: 1.2s; }
    &.pos5 { grid-area: f; --delay: 1.3s; }
    &.pos6 { grid-area: g; --delay: 1.4s; }
    &.pos7 { grid-area: h; --delay: 1.5s; }
  }
```

Here's a simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kbn1rw28/

Comment: thanks a lot! this is great, but I want the animation to be more like a sliding effect.
is it something easy to do?

Comment: Also, it is less important, but currently, I'm allowing to change the number of the grid rows using a react prop.
It seems like the "grid-area" property isn't so flexible.
is there another solution?

Comment: You can create any animation you want, I just pointed you to the 'stacking' option. If you want to 'slide' it, you can add a transform to the animation.

as for the grid-area, don't know why you say it's not flexible, all you need to do is to add a grisWidth and a gridHeight and use them to create the grid's areas dynamically. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/5ebrtqvL/